# Using SplitText plugin of GSAP in React JS

Tags: reactjs, animation, text, importerror, gsap

I am trying to use the SplitText plugin of GSAP in React JS to make a text reveal animation but I am not able to import it in spite of installing gsap. I don't know where to import it from. I have tried `import SplitText from "gsap/SplitText";` but I am getting a not found error. Please help me to understand how to properly install gsap along with its plugins in React JS.

I am trying to replicate this text reveal in my project : [Click Here](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/MWGPJPO)

Answer (score 0):

Installed `gsap-trial` from npm and then import SplitText using `import SplitText from "gsap-trial/SplitText"` and then register the plugin using `gsap.registerPlugin(SplitText);` and now everything will work fine.